# F# Computation Expressions de-sugaring tool

Tags: f#, computation-expression

A great help in dealing with F# computation expressions would be a way to look at how they are de-sugared during compilation.
Is there a way to get the de-sugared version? For example:

1. A tool like `de-sugar ce.fs`
2. A compiler flag to print the output of the de-sugaring process like `fsc --de-sugar-ces ce.fs`
3. A compiler service API like `let desugared = compiler.DeSugar stringOrFilePath`

Decompiling to C# is possible and helps as well, however what I am looking for is the F# de-sugared version, like in

[image]

Comment: You could compile and then decompile to C# using ILSpy

Comment: I use the online decompiler from C# or F# to C# https://sharplab.io/ but the resulting C# is quite verbose. Still it can be used to see what's behind the CE magic, like `Delay` and `Bind` functions

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to understand them is to de-sugar them manually.   The documentation gives some clear [translations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions).  Also be sure to read this excellent i[ntro and examples by F# for fun and profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-intro/).

If you feel brave, you could implement a translator yoursself using [F# compiler services](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/untypedtree.html).

You could walk over the expressions:

```
open FSharp.Compiler.SyntaxTree

| SynExpr.JoinIn 
| SynExpr.ImplicitZero
| SynExpr.YieldOrReturn 
| SynExpr.YieldOrReturnFrom
| SynExpr.LetOrUseBang 
| SynExpr.MatchBang 
| SynExpr.DoBang
```